# Primes taking the form $a+nb$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

If $a,b$ are two coprime positive integers, can we find infinitely many positive integer $n$, such that $a+nb$ is a prime?

Comment: Yes, it's a celebrated result by Dirichlet about primes in arithmetic progressions.

Comment: In fact there are so many primes in this sequence, that the sum of their reciprocals diverges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. This is [Dirichlet's theorem on primes in arithmetic progressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_theorem_on_arithmetic_progressions). The proof is difficult, and is a landmark in the history of number theory, combining ideas from algebraic number theory, the representation theory of finite groups, and the theory of zeta functions.

It is a particular case of the powerful [Chebotarev density theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebotarev%27s_density_theorem).